# Scale video then apply image frame using ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images, overlay, frame

I have an image frame 1920x1080 and a video with the same resolution.

I want to resize video by 80% of its resolution and center it, and then overlay it with image frame. So the final video result is 1920x1080

How i can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -loop 1 -i input_image -t video_duration -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw*80/100:ih*80/100[vo];[1:v][vo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outv]" -c:v libx264 -map [outv] output_video
```

Here you have to use `filter_complex` and `map` for overlaying and do the scaling, etc. `0:v` refers to the input video and it's width and height being [scaled](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale-1) to be 80% of its original. `1:v` refers to the input image and it is [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) with the scaled video to the centre of the image. `loop` will loop the image through out the video duration and `-t` will limit the duration of the output video to seconds you want.

If you need original audio available in the output video use `-map 0:a` before specifying the output file.

```
ffmpeg -i input_video -loop 1 -i input_image -t video_duration -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=iw*80/100:ih*80/100[vo];[1:v][vo]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[outv]" -c:v libx264 -map [outv] -map 0:a -c:a copy output_video
```

Hope this will help you!